# Update Cosmos DB RU using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I have an existing Cosmos database with many collections. RU is set on the collection level.

I want to update collections RU using Powershell on-demand basis. I tried below command but getting below errors

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-CosmosDbOffer -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id 'IuX1' |
Set-CosmosDbOffer -Context $cosmosDbContext -OfferThroughput 555 -OfferIsRUPerMinuteThroughputEnabled $true
```

Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\CosmosDB\2.1.7.675\lib\utils.ps1:562 char:30
+ ... estResult = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing @invokeWebRequestParam ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Any suggestion?? I followed below links but same error

https://github.com/PankajRawat333/CosmosDB#working-with-offers
https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB/wiki/Set-CosmosDbOffer

Comment: I'm not sure about that third party wrapper, but RU/s should be a multiple  of 100 (555 doesn't seem a valid value) and RU/m was a preview feature last year that is no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, it was caused by `-OfferThroughput 555`, as mentioned in the comment, the offerThroughput must be in multiple of `100`, I test with a value like `500`, it works.

[image]

See this link - [Offers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/offers):

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you